# How to move a flex page from bottom to top?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I have a Flex component that is very long. I want to add a save button in the bottom of component. when i click on save button i am changing the state where it displays another component. Do anyone know which function I can use to move a component(screen) from bottom to top? HTML have a Anchor Object to do the same thing.Please give me a idea how to do this in Flex.

Thanks

Comment: Please be more specific: what version of Flex (you used both the Flex3 and Flex4 tags)? what component is your content in? is your Flex app at 100% of the HTML page and does some component take care of the scrolling or is the app bigger than the HTML page? perhaps show some code? either way there is no such thing as a Flex page, there are only components.

Comment: i'm using Group component(Spark), i tried with "verticalScrollPosition", but it didn't work

Comment: Then show some code, because it should (at least if your Group is inside a Scroller).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set property "verticalScrollPosition" to "0" to whatever the component that has the Scroller (the scroll bar).

Comment: Correct, assuming we're dealing with a Spark component. Unfortunately it's impossible to tell from the question (again - sigh).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right, the save button is changing the state of another component. If you want to move the component itself, use the X and Y properties to achieve that. You also can use effects to smooth it out. If that's not what you mean, please clarify the "screen" component.